# Displaying specific web content on android

Tags: android, webview

We make industrial machinery and ship it with Android devices (just like cellphones without the phone) with an installed app that we write to remotely control our equipment from the factory floor.

One customer requested that we interface to some of their equipment which they expose through a web server.   I added a feature to our Android code which invokes the native web browser on our device.    This works but they want the URL the browser is pointing-to be be hardcoded (or hidden) so their workers can't alter it.   Is there a way to do this programmatically from our app?

Alternatively I could use a WebView.   When I experimented using WebViews here at our shop on various commercial web pages, getting the scaling correct for any arbitrary web page was problematic.   What would I need to know about the customer's web page to make sure a WebView would work with their page?

**EDIT:**  Several responders have suggested a WebView and giving the user the option to manually scale it.   The users are factory workers in a production setting, so making them take time to scale would probably not please the customer, and besides they're wearing gloves - all the controls we expose are "fat" buttons - so scaling would be hard.     Really this should look right the first time they see it.    The customer's production facility is on a LAN on the other side of a firewall in another country so I can't access it from here.  Do I need to be able to reproduce it locally do do this right?

Comment: Less than 1 minute after I posted this someone downvoted it, without any comment.   Why?

Comment: not the downvoter but it's something that i see way too often. People will post semi-good or good questions and get immediate downvotes. Sorry

Comment: additionally, could you elaborate on your scaling issue? i made an answer based on the assumption it was a zooming problem but now that I think about it some more I'm not sure what your issue is

Comment: Since I don't have access to the customer's in house server (it's on their LAN in another country) I made a WebView and just set the URL to different arbitrary web pages to test.   The result was some web pages were really tiny and on other you could only see a fraction of the page.  Webviews apparently need to be manually scaled.

Comment: unfortunately, i think you're just going to have to let them manually zoom. Im not aware of a better way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would definitely use the webview. There's just not going to be a way for you to prevent the native browser from potentially changing URLs.

To handle zooming you could just let the users zoom appropriately for themselves:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can block the native browser from accessing other url's, so `WebView` is your best bet.

About what you need to check, I'd simply check if their website is scaling properly on mobile devices. If it does, it should behave the same in a `WebView`. Simply visit the website from a mobile phone/tablet or have a look at their page's code.

Providing the ability for the user to zoom as suggested by iismathwizard is an excellent idea as well.

Best of luck ;)

Comment: Unfortunately the customer's page is local to their factory in another country so I can't see it from our shop.   Is there any way to make a WebView auto-scale or do I need to recreate their web server environment here?

Comment: I'm not aware of any auto-scaling feature for WebView, so I'm going to recommend the same thing as iismathwizard, your best option AFAIK is letting the user handle the zoom manually. If that's really not an option, I suppose you're going to have to reproduce their environment in your development machine.

Comment: Since you have control over the devices they use, and I'm going to guess all users use the same device, there could be something you could do by hardcoding the zoom value when you load the UI, because essentially, you're loading always the same website on the same screen. For example you could try webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true) or webview.setInitialScale(intValueForZoom). It's an ugly solution, but it could work.